# Проблема с servlet'ом

Tags: java, веб-программирование, jsp, servlet

Пытаюсь сделать example.
Создал servlet и файл 1page.jsp в папке web проекта.
Подключил библиотеку http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxservlet30jar.htm .
После запуска приложения вбиваю в браузере "localhost:8080", но выкидывает "веб-страница недоступна". Как это разрешить?

**Код Servlet:**

```
package servlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("html/1page.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

**Код 1page.jsp:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Hello World Sample
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>
            <%
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
            %>
            Hello, world !
            <%            } else {
            %>
            Hello, world ! I'm <%= name%>
            <%
        }
            %>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервлет- это обработчик запросов, для запуска сервера нужен контейнер сервлетов(непосредственно сам сервер)  например [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) или [jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/downloads.php).
Пример запуска можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.tutorialspoint.com//servlets/index.htm)